# preview image i selected in current cell in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

here's my code:

```
private void getit()
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString().Trim() == "")
    {
        OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
        od.ShowDialog();
        if (od.FileName.ToString() != "")
        {
            label2.Text = od.FileName.ToString();
            //pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(label2.Text);

            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = null;
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = Image.FromFile(label2.Text);

            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value = "1";
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = pictureBox4.Image;
                label2.Text = "";
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

[image]

i need to load the image i selected in the cell i just clicked on, it works with picturebox but even when i make 
`dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = pictureBox1.Image` nothing really happen!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure what might be the problem (the column type of the `DataGridView` is wrong?). Here you have a small sample code which should work fine.

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn(new DataGridViewImageCell())); //Adding an image-type column
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); //Adding row 0

OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
od.ShowDialog();
if (od.FileName != "")
{
    label2.Text = od.FileName;
    dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = Image.FromFile(label2.Text);
}
```